# how to use browserify to get firebase-admin module

Tags: browserify, firebase-admin

I need some help regarding how to use the firebase-admin module.

Steps followed:

1. npm install -g browserify
2. added the script:
   `<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script> in my html page`
3. run browserify fireBase.js > bundle.js command in the public folder
4. bundle.js is empty
5. Module name "firebase-admin" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])